# Some PDF Textfield content not visible until clicked

Tags: node.js, pdf

I'm having an issue where the same set of text fields on a form are only visible once clicked. I've read a lot in the Adobe forums about the issue (a decade worth of complaints). I'm wondering if there's some underlying appearance setting that's affecting these fields..

I'm using `pdf-lib` but have the same problem inconsistently with other libraries as well.

Any suggestions on where I might look in the PDF tree for the discrepancy?

[image: Sample pdf image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that the PDFTextFields were not properly marked as `needsUpdateAppearance` when I `setText`, so you can get a little lower and set it on the underlying AcroField:

```js
        textField.acroField.dict.set(
          PDFName.of('NeedAppearances'),
          PDFBool.True
        );
```

as well as on the PDFForm too:

```js
  form.acroForm.dict.set(PDFName.of('NeedAppearances'), PDFBool.True);
  form.updateFieldAppearances();

  const data = await pdfDoc.save();
```

There may be some redundancy with this, but it works so I'm happy.

**NOTE**
Mac's Preview app will still not show the fields, regardless of this fix.

Solution adapted from:
https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/issues/569#issuecomment-1087328416